# Performance differences between filtering a table, scanner, and fragments

Tags: pyarrow

On a large dataset with many files, is there a difference when filtering a dataset directly to a table like this:

```
dataset.to_table(columns, filter=filter_expression)
```

Versus using a scanner like this:

```
dataset.scanner(columns, filter=filter_expression).to_table()
```

Or fragments:

```
fragments = dataset.get_fragments(filter=filter_expression)
new = ds.dataset(fragments)
```

I also notice that scanners and datasets both have a `.take` method. I assume it is always better to use row level filtering with a filter expression instead of using `.take`, right? Or is there a use case I am missing?

Any advice on best practices would be appreciated. My most common use cases are simple partitioning filtering, but also filtering for a certain ID which could exist in basically any partition (for example, I might need all records from a certain ID across the last 2 years).

Comment: Did you notice a performance difference? The first two examples (`dataset.to_table()` and `dataset.scanner().to_table()`) should be exactly equivalent if you use the same filter. The fragments case is not necessarily equivalent in output (you are only filtering per fragment, not the actual rows)

Comment: Oh, good. I have only used the .to_table() method historically and have not tried using a scanner. I just happened to see the scanner documentation was was trying to figure out how it might fit into my workflow at all.